# Calling a module function name in Ajax URL

Tags: ajax

I am developing a custom payment gateway for Drupal Commerce. I am getting some problems calling a custom module function from an AJAX URL.

How do I call a module function from a custom AJAX request?

```
function custom_gateway_settings_form($settings) {
  $form = array();   

  $form['code'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Code'),
    '#maxlength' => 100,
    '#description' => t('Code.'),  
    '#prefix' => '<div id="tabs-code" style = "display:none">',
    '#suffix' =>'</div>',
  );

  $form['btncode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#id' => 'btncode',
    '#value' => 'Get the code',
  );
}
```

The JavaScript code is the following one.

```
   jQuery("#btncode").click(function() { 
     jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST", 
       url: Drupal.settings.basePath + "/?p=ajaxGetCode",
       cache: false,
       beforeSend: function() {
         // jQuery('.loadrimage').show();
         // jQuery(".error").hide();
       },
       complete: function() {
         // jQuery('.loadrimage').hide();
       },   
       success: function(htmlText) {
         alert(htmlText);
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create own endpoint and call post on it. For example create menu element using hook_menu:

```
$items['my-module-ajax-endpoint'] = array(
   'page callback' => 'my_module_ajax_callback', 
   'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver', 
   'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

And now post to it.